# Need help to upgrade perl from 4 to latest

Tags: perl

We are using Perl extensively in our project which is used to fetch the data from DB and install several components. Now we want to upgrade it to 5 from 4.2. I would like to know what changed and what are features that the latest Perl version has over 4.2. Someone please guide me to get this done.

Comment: I don't think you're likely to get a quarter of a century of Perl development condensed into a Stackoverflow answer. Try Wikipedia instead.

Comment: There is no "4.2". The latest perl4 version is 4.036 (released in 1993).

Comment: @melpomene: [4.001..3      1991-Apr-12](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhist.html)

Comment: @Borodin There was also a 4.020 in 1992. Both 4.002 and 4.020 existed for less than a day, superceded by 4.003 and 4.033, respectively. It's unclear what OP is actually using.

Comment: @melpomene: I agree, but I doubt if they meant 4.200

Comment: Sorry It was 4.036 version we have been using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things perl4 didn't have:

- local (lexically scoped) variables
- data structures (beyond simple arrays-of-scalars and hashes-of-scalars)
- references (including references to subroutines, which let you abstract over behavior)
- closures / first-class functions
- OO: classes, methods, and objects
- a module system, and a way to implement parts or all of a module in C, letting you bind to external libraries
- CPAN: a central repository for modules written by other people for almost any task you can think of (current count: 188,959 modules)
- pragmas that can warn you about or disable dangerous and questionable operations (`use strict`, `use warnings`)
- Unicode support (in strings + all core operations; encoding layers in file handles)
- subroutines that can be called like (most) builtins (`&` and parentheses not required, special calling conventions can be enabled by using "prototypes")
- `tie`: a variable (scalar/array/hash) can be backed by an object; operations on the variable automatically invoke methods on the object instead
- threads
- overridable keywords
- exception handling with `die`/`eval {}`
- tons and tons of regex enhancements

... and hundreds of things I don't remember and can't list here. Seriously, perl5 is a very different language from perl4, even if many perl4 features are still there.

Comment: Thank you so much for much needed information. I would like to know does Perl latest version support informix 11.5. Because informix db interaction is the back bone of my application. How about upgrade process, would it be smooth or painful

Comment: @user3291891 Apparently there's a [DBD::Informix](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Informix#NAME) driver, so the standard [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#NAME) (database interface) module should be able to work with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for much needed information. I would like to know does Perl latest version support informix 11.5. Because informix db interaction is the back bone of my application. How about upgrade process, would it be smooth or painful and one last thing is does it have support for code which was written years ago using 4.1.

Comment: @user3291891 As for the upgrade process: You haven't shown any of the code so I can't say. But given that you don't even know what version of perl you're currently using (neither "4.2" nor "4.1" exist), I doubt it's going to be smooth.